# Create 3 side by side panel in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i create 3 panels in bootstrap side by side?
I try with this with out luck:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">Main panel</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-heading">panel 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-heading">panel 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-heading">panel 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
Main panel
    PANEL 1 
    PANEL 2 
    PANEL 3
```

Comment: On my system it works : panel 1, panel 2 and panel 3 are horizontally aligned. Is it what you want ?
I've used :
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could have to use `col-lg-x col-md-x col-sm-x` classes where `x` is the column number.

It is working fine for me after adding proper media width columns. You can check it http://bootply.com/98480 .

If you added `col-sm-x` classes only, then it will not apply to the devices where viewport is less than 768px.